# Weird Python Error Occurring Inside of Torch Serving Library

Tags: python, java, docker, python-3.10, torchserve

I am using BASE_IMAGE=ubuntu:22.04 which comes with python3.10.

Then I proceed to install all my required dependencies, and am able to start the application and listen to the port 8080 correctly.

The Pytorch Server starts the initialization phase correctly and I can see that in my logs. However, It fails on inference. I Believe it never reaches the inference Method because I never see the logs.

However - when I make an inference request, I see the following error:

```
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG - ----- INITIALIZE -----
xyz org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - sent a reply, jobdone: true
xyz org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - sent a reply, jobdone: true
xyz org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Backend response time: 1980
xyz org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Backend response time: 1980
xyz org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - xyz State change WORKER_STARTED -> WORKER_MODEL_LOADED
xyz org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - xyz State change WORKER_STARTED -> WORKER_MODEL_LOADED
xyz TS_METRICS - WorkerLoadTime.Milliseconds:2962.0|#WorkerName:xyz,Level:Host|#hostname:a9cb56cd2a24,timestamp:1688661575
xyz TS_METRICS - WorkerThreadTime.Milliseconds:60.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:a9cb56cd2a24,timestamp:1688661575
pool-2-thread-2 ACCESS_LOG - /172.17.0.1:44710 "GET /ping HTTP/1.1" 200 32
pool-2-thread-2 TS_METRICS - Requests2XX.Count:1.0|#Level:Host|#hostname:a9cb56cd2a24,timestamp:1688661594
epollEventLoopGroup-3-2 TS_METRICS - ts_inference_requests_total.Count:1.0|#model_name:model_xyz,model_version:default|#hostname:a9cb56cd2a24,timestamp:1688661607
xyz org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Flushing req.cmd PREDICT to backend at: 1688661607935
xyz org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Flushing req.cmd PREDICT to backend at: 1688661607935
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG - 
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG - Backend received inference at: 1688661607
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG - Invoking custom service failed.
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG - Traceback (most recent call last):
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ts/service.py", line 134, in predict
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -     ret = self._entry_point(input_batch, self.context)
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ts/torch_handler/request_envelope/base.py", line 26, in handle
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -     data = self.parse_input(data)
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ts/torch_handler/request_envelope/json.py", line 21, in parse_input
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -     lengths, batch = self._batch_from_json(data)
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ts/torch_handler/request_envelope/json.py", line 32, in _batch_from_json
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -     mini_batches = [self._from_json(data_row) for data_row in data_rows]
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ts/torch_handler/request_envelope/json.py", line 32, in <listcomp>
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -     mini_batches = [self._from_json(data_row) for data_row in data_rows]
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -   File "/home/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ts/torch_handler/request_envelope/json.py", line 41, in _from_json
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG -     rows = (data.get("data") or data.get("body") or data)["instances"]
xyz-stdout MODEL_LOG - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```